# Call dependencies using string formatted object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to call dependencies in a string format?

Here are my models:

User

```
has_many :addresses
```

Address

```
belongs_to :user
```

And here is I am trying to do. I want do get all addresses of specific user and I want `"addresses"` to be a string because I want to make it dynamic. For example, I want to change `"some_models_related_to_user"`.

```
user."addresses".first
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it using `send` or `public_send` method:

Instead of this code:

```
user."addresses".first
```

Try below answers:

Using `send`:

```
user.send("addresses").first
```

or using `public_send`:

```
user.public_send("addresses").first
```

Comment: better use `public_send` here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thanks, I update my answer with your suggestion

Comment: Why using `public_send` is much better? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, oh sorry I miss undertood. :) I update my answer again. Thanks for suggestions again.

Comment: public_send functions exactly like send except that it can only use public methods.